# Jquery UI - Combobox Button Height Issue

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

We are using a jquery UI autocomplete widget customized to our needs, one can say it is an extension of the combobox widget seen here. [jquery combobox widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Applying the widget to three select elements on the page, getting a strange issue as shown in the attachment below .

**The button height is not the same as input field height**.

Targetting the button with dev console fetches same styles for all three buttons :(

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

P.S:*And this issue appears at random , sometime for the second element , sometime third.*

[image: Third Combobox button height is not the same as others]

EDIT :This may be a problem with the custom CSS  or jquery Library CSS, cuz i am able to fix it by adding a

```
    element.style{
          height:33px;
    }
```

to the anchor tag which server as the button, but i am not sure if that is the right thing to do.

EDIT : The jsfiddle link can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luciferous/9BctV/2/)

Comment: Only with an image is impossible to help you; try to made up a demo on jsfiddle or elsewhere

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Added jsFiddle... But i reckon one may see it in the official jquery UI combobox link itself using chrome.

Comment: Works fine on Safari for Mac, I'm checking why

Comment: Any suggestions/comments/reveleations/discoveries yet ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle works well if you set:

```
.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
}
```

I think it's related oh how Webkit consider decimal em in this situation, but it must be ivestigated more deeply.

From jQuery UI bugs forum:

> The combobox is just a demo, it's not a fully complete widget. We
>   won't maintain functionality beyond our demo unless we pull combobox
>   in as an official plugin that we support.

Link: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6133

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/WU9v9/

Comment: Well ,sadly as mentioned in the question, i had fixed it by pixel hunting only :) Hope they fix it in the near future . Accepting !